# work with chunked data while groupby operations are needed

Tags: python, pandas, pytables, hdfstore

I have a dataset `df` with three columns: `'String_key_val'`, `'Float_other_val1'`, `'Int_other_val2'`. I want to groupby on key_val, then extract the sum of `val1` (resp. `val2`) with respect to these groups. Here is my code:

```
df = pandas.read_csv('test.csv')
grouped = df.groupby('String_key_val')
series_calculus1 = grouped['Float_other_val1'].sum()
series_calculus2 = grouped['Int_other_val2'].sum()

res = pandas.concat([series_calculus1, series_calculus2], axis=1)
res.to_csv('output_test.csv')
```

My problem is: My entry dataset is 10GB and I have 4Go Ram so I need to chunk my calculus but I can't see how. I thought of using `HDFStore`, but since I only have to build a numerical dataset, I see no point of storing complete `DataFrame`, and I don't think `HDFStore` can store simple arrays.
What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I believe a simple approach would be something along these lines....

```
import pandas as pd

summary = pd.DataFrame()
chunker = pd.read_csv('test.csv',iterator=True,chunksize=50000)

for chunk in chunker:
    group = chunk.groupby('String_key_val')
    out = group[['Float_other_val1','Int_other_val2']].sum()
    summary = summary.append(out)
    summary = summary.reset_index()
    group = summary.groupby('String_key_val')
    summary = group[['Float_other_val1','Int_other_val2']].sum()
```